# Indexing large objects into ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, symfony, foselasticabundle

I am trying to index large objects - objects with lots of relations (about 100'000) - into ElasticSearch index, but the objects don't fit into memory. Sometimes Postgres limit is exceeded, sometimes PHP. And I cannot increase the limits any more.

Records are fetched one-by-one, on-demand. Page size has been minimized to 1.

Framework is Symfony3, bundle is FOSElasticaBundle.

Any bright ideas? Write indexed object into disk?

Answer (score -1):

well it's a know problem, indexing with php / ORM is slow. You should have a look at the [Java JDBC elasticsearch importer](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc) which is far more faster.

Comment: But how would this solve my problem, if I dont have enough memory to fetch even one object? :) It would make things faster, I give you that.

Comment: The memory consumption of Java has nothing to do with PHP. Moreover this elasticsearch feeder is optimized for memory and speed.

Comment: It isnt just PHP memory problem, but Postgres as well. See my original post.

Comment: Add memory to postgres then.

Comment: Cant do that. See my original post.

Comment: Then don't use elastisearch.

Comment: Thanks, I start to refactor my app right away. So does this mean that if I switch ElasticSearch to something else (e.g Azure) these problems disappear?